# Need some explanation about BeanNameViewResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i read the documentation here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/BeanNameViewResolver.html

but i think that the spring documentation sometimes can become complex and hard to understand, so i need little explanation about this class.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As described in the documentation, `BeanNameViewResolver` resolves `View`s declared as beans. Usually you need it for some special-purpose views.

Imagine, for example, that one of your controllers should render an Excel spreadsheet. So, you subclass `AbstractExcelView` and implement your custom logic to render a spreadsheet based on model values:

```
public class MyExcelView extends AbstractExcelView { ... }
```

and declare it as a bean:

```
<bean id = "myExcelView" class = "MyExcelView" />
```

Then declaring an `BeanNameViewResolver` makes it available to controllers: when controller returns `ModelAndView` with view name `myExcelView`, your spreadsheet will be rendered.

`BeanNameViewResolver` is usually used in conjunction with some other view resolver that handles "regular" views (so that if `BeanNameViewResolver` can't find a view, the other resolver tries to find it):

```
<bean class = "...BeanNameViewResolver">
    <property name = "order" value = "0" />
</bean>

<bean class = "...InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name = "order" value = "1" />
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: +1 for being faster than me and have some details my blob doesnt have :)

Comment: +1 for good explanation. A couple of questions: 1) does beannameviewresolver need to be thread-safe? 2) is internalresourceviewresolver thread-safe?

Answer (score 8):

Indeed the documentation is not fantastic.

The view resolver in spring mvc is a bean which translates from view names to views.

A view name is s simple string. It is returned by the controller's handleRequest() method within the ModelAndView object.

```
ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ....
    return ModelAndView("thisIsTheViewName", ...);
}
```

This view name is resolved to an actual view class by the view resolver.

The BeanNameViewResolver has an easy job: It looks for a view bean in the applicationContext which has this view name as its id.

```
<bean id="thisIsTheViewName" class="....MyView" />
```

For simple applications this can be the simplest way to translate from view name to view.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a very simple but complete example:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String getHello() {
        return "helloView";
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class HelloView extends AbstractView {

    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> map,
              HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
        res.setContentType("text/plain");
        res.getOutputStream().println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you said "Complete", it would be good to add how "HelloView" is registered as well. :)